# Show td if two conditions are satisfied

Tags: jquery

I have form submit on my php web page. On this form i have checkbox.

if form submit button is clicked and check box is checked i want to hide td in a table.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
            {

                $('#formclick').on('submit'), function(){
                    $('#check').change(function(){
                        if(this.checked)
                        $("#cell").hide();
                    else 
                        $("#cell").show();
                        });

                });

            });
</script>

<table>
<td>something</td>
<td id="cell">this has to be hide wheen formclick submit is clicked and checkbox is checked</td>
<td>something</td>
<td>something</td>
<td>something</td>
<td>something</td>
</table>
```

some help ?

Comment: You need to explain your problem a little more — you do know that a form, when submitted, will redirect users to a new page?

Comment: its redirecting on same page please see comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is a little strange because you are listening on the submit event of what I assume is a `<form>` element without preventing form submission. Form submission will trigger a URL redirect, so without any further information I suppose you do not intend to redirect user to another page.

It is convoluted to bind event handlers within event listeners. Instead, use conditional statement to evaluate if the checkbox is indeed checked upon form submission:

```
$('#formclick').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#check').is(':checked')) {
        $('#cell').hide();        
    } else {
        $('#cell').show();
    }
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/p1jxt3fv/

Comment: I am sending to php file, but its on same page :
[link]<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="formclick">

Comment: Then you don't even need JS. You simply check the PHP $_POST or $_GET object for the value of the checkbox. If present, hide the cell; if not, don't. Alternatively you can store the status of the checkbox upon submission in a cookie, or in local storage.

Comment: Thank you man !! I did not know that holding checkbox is posible :D
this is how to if any get hooked with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046312/save-value-of-checkboxes-in-a-form-with-php