# How to save state of a checkbox in wordpress plugin's.php file after page reload?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a checkbox in a table in my functions.php, in the following way:

```
 echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkblock"/></td><td> ' . $image . '</td><td>' . $name . '</td><td>' . $qtty . '</td></tr>';
```

What I need is to be able to save the state of the checkbox on page reload, as this is only needed temporarily while the user is using this page, I don't need anything saving in the database, I have tried following guidance from similar questions in stack overflow and off the internet but it always crashes my site.

I have tried the following in this question: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313595/saving-checkbox-state-on-reload)

Also I have tried following this: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046312/save-value-of-checkboxes-in-a-form-with-php) (Although I am not using a form).

I have tried using and following articles and questions off the internet but It either does not work or crashes my site. One difference is others are editing in HTML and JS files whilst I am just using my functions.php and have created the checkbox input option using the line of code above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Javascript's **localStorage** would help you.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof localStorage["checkblock"] !== "undefined") {
      document.getElementById("checkblock").checked = localStorage.getItem("checkblock") === 'true';
    }
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    setInterval(function () {
      localStorage.setItem('checkblock', document.getElementById("checkblock").checked);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkblock" id="checkblock" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, so yeah that worked! I was able to save the state of the checkbox, but now there is another issue. The checkbox  is in a table and there are multiple checkboxes (depending on how many rows of data in the table, all checkboxes have the same ID but code only saves the state of the first checkbox after checking it, can this be done so it saves the checked state of any of these checkboxes that all have the same ID?

Comment: @Swifter Sorry for late response. I was a little busy last week. The more you give exact description of your issues, the more accurate answer you will get. Next time, please try to be more oriented on your goals. About the issue, I would suggest to use prepared JavaScript modules from github like https://github.com/appleple/form-storage. Because you will not need to complain about pitfalls. Everything is ready :)